# jQuery page changes then changes back

Tags: jquery, html, forms, coldfusion

In jQuery, I have a form that submits, grabs data from a database using ColdFusion, and then displays some of that data on a new page. Problem is, whenever I switch to the new page, it flashes on for a second, and then redirects me back to the start page. [Here](http://psc.carthage.edu/tests/yup.html#permit) is the page in question. Just type in 9355 as the permit number you want to search for.

Here is the code behind it:

**Permit Page**

```
 <div data-role="page" id = 'permit' data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Parking Permit Number Search</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><br></div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                <form id="formpermit">
                    <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="permittext" id="permittext" value="">
                </form>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#formpermit").on("submit",function() {
                    $.mobile.changePage("#Student");
                });         
                </script>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                <!-- <a href='#Student' data-role="button" onclick="formpermit.submit()" data-inline="true">Search</a> -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- /grid solo -->   
        </div><!-- /content --> 
        <a href='#bug' data-rel="dialog" onclick="clearText()" data-close-btn="left" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Report bug</a>
    </div> <!--/Permit Number -->
```

**Student Page**

```
<div data-role="page" id = 'Student' data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Student Info Page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#formpermit").on("submit",function() {                       
            var strPermit=$(permittext).val();
                strPermit=$.trim(strPermit);

                $.get("joeyP.cfm", { Permit: strPermit})
                .done(function(data) {
                  $("#myResults").html(data);
                });                
            });
        </script>
        <div id="myResults"></div>
    </div> <!-- /content -->
    <a href='#first' data-role="button" data-inline="true">Back</a>
</div> <!--/Student -->
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the page that does the submission to continue by returning `false` from the event handler:

```
$("#formpermit").on("submit",function() {
   ... 
   return false;
});
```

probably in both your cases.

Answer (score 1):

When you click a submit button your browser will post the data in a new request.

You should prevent this default behaviour. You can do this with the `preventDefault()` function on the `event` object. The `event` object get's passed as first parameter to the callback function of your listener.

```
$("#formpermit").on("submit", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault()

    // rest of your code here

})
```

Comment: for some reason, preventDefault isn't working for me... Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Zorpix make sure you pass the event into your function.  `function(event){}`